# I need to use double instead of int for my outcome to be correct. Why? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, int, double, average

Today i tried to make a simple program in Java that gives me the average of the numbers i entered.

The problem is that if i use int added (as shown below), i don't get the same answer as when i use double added.

Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int amount;
        int number;
        int added = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program calculates the average of the numbers entered by you.");
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        amount = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i<=amount; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            number = input.nextInt();
            added = added + number;
        }

        average = added/amount;
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers entered is: " + average);

    }

}
```

Result:

```
This program calculates the average of the numbers entered by you.
How many numbers do you want to enter?
6
Enter a number:
3
Enter a number:
2
Enter a number:
4
Enter a number:
1
Enter a number:
6
Enter a number:
5
The average of the numbers entered is: 3.0
```

When i use double, i get the right answer:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int amount;
        int number;
        double added = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program calculates the average of the numbers entered by you.");
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        amount = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=1; i<=amount; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            number = input.nextInt();
            added = added + number;
        }

        average = added/amount;
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers entered is: " + average);

    }

}
```

Result when i use double added instead of int added:

```
This program calculates the average of the numbers entered by you.
How many numbers do you want to enter?
6
Enter a number:
3
Enter a number:
2
Enter a number:
4
Enter a number:
1
Enter a number:
6
Enter a number:
5
The average of the numbers entered is: 3.5
```

Why does this happen and what should i do to avoid it?
To me it seems like added could be an int because i don't add up decimals but i add up whole numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The result of integer division is an `int`, which does not have a decimal part.

Comment: Right: int x = y/z will return x = 0 for all z > y when all are integers.  True in Java, C, C++, C#, etc.

Comment: So `(int) 5/2 will be 2` (int is actually 2.5 but the .5 is ignored) `(double) 5/2 will be 2.5` (double is capable to store it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `added/amount` to return a non integer, either `added` or `amount` must be `float` or `double` or cast to either of them.

When both are `int`, an integer division takes place and the result is only converted to `double` after the division in order to be stored in your `double` `average` variable.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a division in which *both* elements are integer, will be an integer. At least one of them needs to be a float or a double for the result of the division to be a floating point number.

Comment: I will remember that. Thank you.